# Abot Crawler Omit CrawledPage HttpWebRequest/Response

Tags: c#, web-crawler, httprequest, httpresponse, cefsharp

I am using Abot in a way that I have a WPF application which displays a browser control (CefSharp).
The user logs in and whichever possible custom authentication the site is using will work while crawling in the same way as if the user were actually browsing the site.

Thus, when I crawl, I want to use this browser control to make the request and simply return the page data.
Therefore I've implemented my custom PageRequester, complete listing below.

The problem is that with CefSharp, as with other browser controls, it's not possible to get the HttpWebRequest/Response associated with a CrawlPage.
Without setting these two properties, Abot does not proceed the crawl further.

Is there something I can do to circumvent this problem?

Code listing:

```
using Abot.Core;
using Abot.Poco;
using CefSharp.Wpf;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class CefPageRequester : IPageRequester
{
    private MainWindowDataContext DataContext;
    private ChromiumWebBrowser ChromiumWebBrowser;
    private CrawlConfiguration CrawlConfig;

    private volatile bool _navigationCompleted;
    private string _pageSource;

    public CefPageRequester(MainWindowDataContext dataContext, ChromiumWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, CrawlConfiguration crawlConfig)
    {
        this.DataContext = dataContext;
        this.ChromiumWebBrowser = chromiumWebBrowser;
        this.CrawlConfig = crawlConfig;

        this.ChromiumWebBrowser.FrameLoadEnd += ChromiumWebBrowser_FrameLoadEnd;
    }

    public CrawledPage MakeRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        return this.MakeRequest(uri, cp => new CrawlDecision() { Allow = true });
    }

    public CrawledPage MakeRequest(Uri uri, Func<CrawledPage, CrawlDecision> shouldDownloadContent)
    {
        if (uri == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");

        CrawledPage crawledPage = new CrawledPage(uri);

        try
        {
            //the browser control is bound to the address of the data context, 
            //if we set the address directly it breaks for some reason, although it's a two way binding.
            this.DataContext.Address = uri.AbsolutePath;

            crawledPage.RequestStarted = DateTime.Now;
            crawledPage.DownloadContentStarted = crawledPage.RequestStarted;

            while (!_navigationCompleted)
                Thread.CurrentThread.Join(10);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            crawledPage.WebException = e;
        }
        catch
        {
            //bad luck, we should log this.
        }
        finally
        {
            //TODO must add these properties!!
            //crawledPage.HttpWebRequest = request;
            //crawledPage.HttpWebResponse = response;
            crawledPage.RequestCompleted = DateTime.Now;
            crawledPage.DownloadContentCompleted = crawledPage.RequestCompleted;
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_pageSource))
                crawledPage.Content = this.GetContent("UTF-8", _pageSource);

            _navigationCompleted = false;
            _pageSource = null;
        }

        return crawledPage;
    }

    private void ChromiumWebBrowser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, CefSharp.FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsMainFrame)
            return;

        this.ChromiumWebBrowser.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            (Action)(() =>
            {
                _pageSource = this.ChromiumWebBrowser.GetSourceAsync().Result;
                _navigationCompleted = true;
            }));
    }

    private PageContent GetContent(string charset, string html)
    {
        PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
        pageContent.Charset = charset;
        pageContent.Encoding = this.GetEncoding(charset);
        pageContent.Text = html;
        pageContent.Bytes = pageContent.Encoding.GetBytes(html);

        return pageContent;
    }

    private Encoding GetEncoding(string charset)
    {
        Encoding e = Encoding.UTF8;
        if (charset != null)
        {
            try
            {
                e = Encoding.GetEncoding(charset);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        return e;
    }
}
```

The question can also be phrased as: how to avoid having to create a HttpWebResponse from a stream? Which seems impossible, given MSDN [says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You should never directly create an instance of the HttpWebResponse
>   class. Instead, use the instance returned by a call to
>   HttpWebRequest.GetResponse.

I would have to actually post the request to get the response, which is precisely what I want to avoid by having a web browser control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are aware, lots of functionality depends on the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse being set. I've ordered a few options for you off the top of my head...

1) Refactor Abot to use some POCO Abstraction instead of those classes. Then just  have an converter that converts the real HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to those POCO types as well as a converter that converts your browser objects response into those POCOs.

2) Create a CustomHttpWebRequest and CustomHttpWebResponse that inherit from the .net classes so you can access/override the public/protected properties which may allow you to manually create an instance that models the request/response that your browser component returns to you. I know this can be tricky but may work (I've never done it so I can't say for sure).

3) **[I HATE THIS IDEA. It SHOULD BE YOUR LAST RESORT]** Create a real instance of these classes and use reflection to set whatever properties/values need to be set to satisfy all of Abot's usages.

4) **[I HATE THIS IDEA EVEN WORSE]** Use MS Fakes to create shims/stubs/fakes to the properties and methods of the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse. Then you could configure it to return your values. This tool is usually only used for testing but I believe it can be used for production code if you are desperate, don't care about performance and/or are insane.

I also included the terrible ideas as well to just in case they help you spark some thought. Hope that helps...

Comment: So, refactoring was simpler than I imagined, I could've looked into that before asking. 2 is impossible, and I didn't go below.